# Azure Proxy, CORS error when request IIS hosted API

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, proxy, asp.net-core-webapi

I hosted a WebAPI in IIS and now because I need to access my API from everywhere I create an azure proxy but every time that I use my UI to make a request, I get this error:
[image]

startup.cs

ConfigureServices

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed((string v) => _ = true)
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
                });
        });
```

Configure

```
            app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

if I run my front-end code in the network where the IIS is and instead of calling the proxy call the API's localhost it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need add `mycors` rule in ConfigureServices. For more details, you can read [the offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>options.AddPolicy("mycors",
             p => p.AllowAnyOrigin())
        );
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }
```

Then apply `mycors` in `Configure` function.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        //*****apply mycors****

        app.UseCors("mycors"); 

        //*********************


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

I depoly my two project. You can see source code, and I have achieve cross-domain functionality.

[image]

Comment: Sorry taking to long to responde, but i took a  look into the corss error and notice that when acessing the proxy if the proxy returns 401 Unauthorized the message that is receive refers to cors even if it isnt at all a cors error. Because that mensage is the result from 401 response during negociate. I think i will need to rethink the project structure.